# Import csv into SQL Server table

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis

I was a developer a long time ago and moved into a management position but back to doing some light development with a new role.

The problem I have is that I need to import a `.csv` file into a SQL Server table for further processing which I have working but one column may have a "," in it that is blowing up the import.

I know it works whenever I force the "," to be removed but need to be able to do this programmatically. The file comes from an external source so unfortunately I don't have the ability to have the source corrected or to place " " around the column as a delimiter.

Any help or suggestion would be appreciated.

PS: please keep in mind that I'm re-learning stuff so you may have to "dumb" down any suggestions. ;)

steve

Comment: The computer isn't going to have the awareness or the context to know that a comma is part of a value instead of a delimiter. You'll need to preprocess the CSV file to add the quotes around the value containing the comma. You already suggested that might be a solution, so I won't go into detail about that since it seems you already know. Ideally, the external source would be corrected to stop producing a malformed CSV file in the first place.

Comment: What are you using to read your CSV file? Either your CSV is malformed (i.e., the data containing the comma is not quoted) or what you're using to read the CSV is broken.

Comment: In standard CSV, when you have a comma within the data, that field must be enclosed with quotes. First check the file has that correct formating, and if not, ask the producer to submit a proper format.

Comment: Run sqlcmd.exe from a bat file which has a csv inport feature.  Runs much quicker that doing same in c#.  You can run the bat file from a c# Process Class.  the SQLCMD commands are also in a PowerShell.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/command-prompt-utility-reference-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Beyond the sage advice of the other commentors, it sounds like your constraints are such that you cannot influence the source file and the out of the box tooling does not support your case, then you need to roll your own method. _I_ would advocate writing a pre-processor step that takes the malformed CSV and produces a well-formed one. It could as simple as `readline -> split on comma => if split count is expected, recombine; if split count is one greater than expected, merge columns N and N+1 and then recombine ` The advantage of this approach is you can compare original input to new input

Comment: Trying to do it all in a single pass is going to be the devil to debug when a new scenario comes up and further breaks your source CSV

Comment: It sounds like it be worth trying to have a conversation with whoever provides the source file. Of course it may not be possible to have that conversation, but if it is, they may be willing to add a text qualifier.

Answer (score 0):

What you actually can do if you are working with c# is  to identify exactly where the comma is, for example if you have a table like this:

```
Apple,Peach,Raspberry
Apple,Banana,grape
Tomato,Pe,ch,Raspberry
```

if you can see usually there is 3 columns separated by comma, and right in the 3th column there is an extra comma in the Peach word, so if the comma always appears on the second column you can count the words per line:

```
var contents = File.ReadAllText(filename).Split('\n');
//you can use linq
var csv = from line in contents select line.Split(',').ToArray();
var count = contents.Split(',').Length;
```

//Usually it will always count 3, but when it counts 4 then you can use an if condition, right on that colum:

```
if(count > 3){

col2 = csv[1] + csv[2]

}
```

I mean this is just the Idea and quick answer, but depends of the way you are doing it, you just have to find the right pattern of that CSV so you figure how to work around!